# How would I add a "add" button to this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

Sorry for my lack of knowing JS. But I have this Jquery dialog code and need to add a button that says "Add" and would call a new blank dialog? I'm a UX/UI designer and syntax messes me up, lol. Any help would be great.

```
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});

$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog(  "option", "width", 650  );
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog( "open" );
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The buttons property is a javascript [literal object](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php), so you can add a button like this:

```
buttons: {
    Ok: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    },
    Add : function() {
      $('#otherDialog').dialog("open");
    }
}
```

As you can see, they are functions separated by comma and the name will be used as text.

Comment: Good answer. (+1) To @Tony, I would recommend learning a bit more about JavaScript syntax. Even though you are a UI designer, given how that line is blurring more and more between writing some client-side code and developing the UI/UX, it's a good skill to have. There are numerous tutorials on the web if you search around a bit.

Comment: @JasCav, Yeah, standard Html, CSS and editing some JS I can do but if it doesn't jump right out then I kind of go huh. LOL

Comment: @sergio - Thanks for the answer and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
            width: 650,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```